# ToolStipMenuItem.ToolTipText

Tags: c#, winforms

Если на каждом элементе `ToolStipMenuItem` написать какой-то текст в свойстве tooltiptext то иногда когда наводишь мышью на последний элемент он начинает моргать и то показывать `ToolTipText` то нет, и при этом на него проблематично кликнуть. Когда убираю `ToolTipText` на последнем элементе всё становится нормально, но для меня это не решение. Что делать?

[image: гифка]

Или можно изменить время через которое появляется `ToolTipText`? 
Имею ввиду изменить время через которое появляется `ToolTipText`?

Comment: неужели так критично использовать tooltiptext

Comment: @newbie очень желательно

Comment: ну я у себя попробовал тоже самое сделать, но такой проблемы у меня не наблюдается.

Comment: @newbie надо просто направить на предпоследнюю и когда уже на ней почти появится tooltiptext перевести на последнюю

Answer (score 2):

Время появления `ToolTip` можно изменить вот так:

```
ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();

///Интервал времени в миллисекундах, в течение которого указатель мыши должен 
///оставаться в границах элемента управления, прежде чем появится окно всплывающей 
///подсказки.

tip.InitialDelay = 500;

///Интервал времени в миллисекундах, который должен пройти перед появлением 
///следующего окна всплывающей подсказки.

ToolTip1.ReshowDelay = 100; 

///Интервал времени в миллисекундах, в течение которого подсказка ToolTip остается видимой, 
///когда указатель мыши останавливается на элементе управления.Значение по умолчанию — 5000.

ToolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
```